# Cannot get new <select> value from dropdown in Bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors, modal-dialog, html-select

UPDATE _ PROBLEM RESOLVED.  See my posted comments below.

Original:

I have an image editing UI that pulls image data from a MYSQL database and displays it for editing in a Bootstrap 4 modal.  The user updates the data then submits it to my php function via ajax for updating the database.  I have input elements for image title, caption, and a dropdown/select for the image category.

All but the select element for the image category works.  I can't seem to get the new value from the modal select dropdown.

This is the "show current values" code, which works fine:

```
$("#imageeditModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {

        var theimageId = ($(".card.selected img").attr("data-imageId"));
        var thecategory = ($(".card.selected img").attr("data-categoryid"));

        var theimage = ($(".card.selected img").attr("src"));
        var thecaption = ($(".card.selected p#image-caption").html());
        var thetitle = ($(".card.selected p#image-title").html());

        $("#caption").val(thecaption);
        $("#title").val(thetitle);
        $(".modal-body #imageCategory").val(thecategory);   

        $("#imageeditAlert").hide();

    });
```

Following is the code for picking up the new values when the user submits the image (cut off prior to ajax call for clarity)....note that the "alert" always shows the original value, not the new selected value!!

```
$("#imageeditButton").click(function() {

        var newtitle = $("#title").val().trim();
        var newcaption = $("#caption").val().trim();
        var newcategory = $(".modal-body #imageCategory").val();
        var theimage = ($(".card.selected img").attr("data-imageId"));
        alert(newcategory);
```

As I said, the title and caption work flawlessly and pick up the new/updated data.  However the imageCategory select value always remains the original/default, regardless of the user's new choice in the dropdown.

I assumed that when user selects a value in select dropdown, the element "magically" gets set to the new value, so that my Jquery statement can pick it up.  No?  What am I missing here?   Do I have to set up an onChange event or something to pull new values?  I thought the bootstrap select element took care of all that automagically.

Comment: Ok, I don't think anyone will find an issue.  I took the above two functions and the modal and built a simple index.html file and set  the "default" var values with strings vs pulling the data.  Not that it mattered... the select dropdown worked perfectly.  Then I took the working code and put it BACK into my original file, and it does NOT work.  Something somewhere else must be disabling the select dropdown or JQUERY's ability to pull the new values.  I proved the above code works, but inside my broader code set it doesn't.  Same bootstrap scripts, etc., etc.  I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: Solved.  Sorry for the headfake but this was a good learning for me.  In addition to the edit image modal and functions I have an image UPLOAD modal and function which has the same drop-down for image category with the same element id.  My bad.  New as I am, I figured with only one modal "active" at a time it wouldn't matter.  Apparently that's not the case.   I can now set defaults from the image data, grab new values, and update the db.    I'm of a mind to delete this whole thread but not sure what the protocol is.....